# How to format "git describe" output in simple file with .bat script?

Tags: git, batch-file, format, git-describe

I want to get output in simple txt file inside git repo folder:

```
About:
date = (2022_06_04)
version = (1d34a1b1)
```

And I stuck with formatting data in ( ) brackets.

Here is my attempt:

```
@echo off
set dt=%DATE:~6,4%_%DATE:~3,2%_%DATE:~0,2%%
set dt=%dt: =0%
set wrap=About:
set file_name="vers.txt"
set git_cmd=git describe --abbrev=8 --always
echo %wrap% >%file_name%
echo.date = (%dt%)>>%file_name%
echo|set /p ="version = (" >>%file_name%
%git_cmd% >>%file_name%
echo.) >>%file_name%
%NL%>>%file_name%
```

Problem is with ')' for git output formatting. Here is what I'm getting:

```
About: 
date = (2022_06_04)
version = (1d34a1b1
)
```

I've tried to play with `echo -n`, but it doesn't work on Windows.

**UPDATE**

NL is just new line:

```
set NL=echo.
```

Here is example of command line with whole git command output:

```
USR@DESKTOP-N1 MINGW64 /c/project/prj (v1.1.2)<CR><LF>
$ git describe --abbrev=8 --always<CR><LF>
1d34a1b1<CR><LF>
<CR><LF>
USR@DESKTOP-N1 MINGW64 /c/project/prj (v1.1.2)<CR><LF>
```

And here is how my output text file looks like:

```
About:<CR><LF>
date = (2022_06_06)<CR><LF>
version = (1d34a1b1<LF>
) <CR><LF>
```

Seems `<LF>` appeared at some stage. For me it looks like `<CR>` was cutted but `<LF>` stayed because of some Windows standard formatting or something like that, I'm no sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities leap to mind

```
%git_cmd%|set /p ="version = (" >>%file_name%
echo.) >>%file_name%
```

and

```
for /f "delims=" %%e in ('%git_cmd%') do echo version = (%%e)>>%file_name%
```

but I've no `git` applications, so this is a guess...

---

This worked for me to give the output desired:

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
set dt=%date%
set wrap=About:
set file_name="u:\vers.txt"
set git_cmd=q72496859s describe --abbrev=8 --always
echo %wrap% >%file_name%
echo.date = (%dt%)>>%file_name%
for /f "delims=" %%e in ('%git_cmd%') do echo version = (%%e)>>%file_name%

TYPE %file_name%

GOTO :EOF
```

Noting:
My `%date%` format is YYYYMMDD

I've removed the `%NL%...` line. `NL` is not defined in the original post. I'd guess it's supposed to add a new line.

`q72496859s` is a batch file that simply responds `1d34a1b1` on a single line.

I've no idea what `git` actually generates - does it contain empty lines or perhaps `<CR><LF><CR>` sequences?

It's SOP for me to use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces and not assign a terminal `\`, Space or `"` - but build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier.

Using these principles, this batch becomes

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
set "dt=%date%"
set "wrap=About:"
set "file_name=u:\vers.txt"
set "git_cmd=q72496859s describe --abbrev=8 --always"
echo %wrap% >"%file_name%"
ECHO date = (%dt%)>>"%file_name%"
for /f "delims=" %%e in ('%git_cmd%') do echo version = (%%e)>>"%file_name%"

TYPE "%file_name%"

GOTO :EOF
```

Edit to second version of above.

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
set "dt=%date%"
set "wrap=About:"
set "file_name=u:\vers.txt"
set "git_cmd=q72496859s describe --abbrev=8 --always"
echo %wrap% >"%file_name%"
ECHO date = (%dt%)>>"%file_name%"
```

for /f "delims=" %%e in ('%git_cmd% ^|findstr /v "/ -"') do echo version = (%%e)>>"%file_name%"

```
TYPE "%file_name%"

GOTO :EOF
```

I set `q72496859s` to deliver the `git` response described.

The pipe needs to be escaped (by a caret) to tell `cmd` that it's part of the command-to-be-executed, not of the actual `for` command.

The `findstr` ignores empty lines and reports those lines that do not (/v) contain either `/` or `-` - the `/` needs to be escaped (using backslash this time), which should isolate the required data.

The result I obtained was

```
About:
date = (06/06/2022)
version = (1d34a1b1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. First one gives: _version = ()_ and second dont print nothing at all in row with version. First 2 lines with "about" and "date" I didn't mention as they print as expected.

Comment: Here is example of whole git command output:

USR@DESKTOP-N1 MINGW64 /c/project/prj (v1.1.2)`<CR><LF>`
$ git describe --abbrev=8 --always`<CR><LF>`
1d34a1b1`<CR><LF>`
`<CR><LF>`
USR@DESKTOP-N1 MINGW64 /c/project/prj (v1.1.2)`<CR><LF>`


Your last batch file gives nothing in last sequence for some reason.

Also I have examined initial output (pls see update of question), it occurs there are `<LF>` appeared before ')'.

Comment: I have updated question header, to keep better formatting

Comment: thanks for assistance! Your last modification worked if change `findstr` to `find` (its happened because of command line text encoding, `find` command supports UTF-16, `findstr` dont. But now my output as I wanted!